# Реально ли открыть Активити в Активити?

Tags: android, listview, webview, activity

Привет.

Есть MainActivity, в котором есть 4 вкладки (TabHost и TabWidget), в каждой вкладке свои активити подгружаются, все они подобные. В них ListView, который берет данные с инета! По клику на каждый пункт должен открываться WebView.

Все это у меня работает. Но есть одно "но": ВебВью открывается как бы по верх всего, а должен открываться в MainActivity и в той же вкладке, где его и открыли, т.е. при открытии WebView тоже должны быть видны табы.

Не подскажите как сделать?

Comment: меняйте логику на фрагменты. на них все это хорошо реализуется

Comment: менять уже не вариант, почти готовое приложение

Comment: Тогда договаривайтесь с гуглом, чтобы меняли архитектуру приложений.
Что значит "не вариант"? Рефакторинг кода - вполне стандартная процедура. Еще не раз так прийдется поступить, если дальше будете что-нибудь разрабатывать.

Comment: Спасибо)) я уже это понял, буду переделывать)) лучше изначально внести изминения ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Активити в активити отобразить *нельзя*, однако можно схитрить.
**Я прошу вас очень тщательно обдумать написание такого кода**, прислушайтесь к совету @monomi про `Fragments`!
Итак, если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите получить результат, похожий на этот:

```
жёлтое - часть родительской активити, которую хотите видеть при работающем WebView
зелёное - дочерняя активити с WebView, показывающаяся поверх всего
```

[image]
Приступим!
 1. Открываем `AndroidManifest.xml`, ищем дочернюю активити с `WebView` и добавляем:
    `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`
 2. Открываем код родительской активити и выполняем расчёт размеров дочерней активити. Нам понадобятся размеры экрана и высота `ActionBar`. Как всё это получить - гуглите. Теперь немного псевдокода:

```
ширинаАктивити = ширинаЭкрана;
высотаАктивити = высотаЭкрана - высотаЭкшнбара;
```

`3`. Теперь добавляем высоту, ширину и остальные данные в `Intent` и стартуем дочернюю активити. В `onCreate` дочерней активити пишем код:

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent(); //сначала любым нужным для вас способом получите отправленные данные
//получаем переданные высоту и ширину
int width = mIntent.getIntExtra(...);
int height = mIntent.getIntExtra(...);
//Настраиваем окно дочерней активити
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.width = width; //устанавливаем ширину
lp.height = height; //...и высоту
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; //опускаем окно вниз
getWindow().setAttributes(lp); //применяем настройки
//И ТОЛЬКО ПОТОМ ВЫЗЫВАЕМ setContentView И ВСЁ ОСТАЛЬНОЕ!!!
```

Comment: спасибо огромное за ответ и за совет)))
Подскажите пожалуйста где мне почитать о фрагментах информацию, особенно интересует взаимодействие с табами. А табы что бы можно было максимально кастомизировать